# OneSignal push notifications don't link correctly to my GoNative app

Tags: mobile, push, onesignal

**I am answering my own question here in case anyone runs into a similar problem.**

I recently have been working with **GoNative** to spin up a hybrid native application for [DoneDone](https://www.donedone.com), a task management and shared inbox tool.

I am also using [**OneSignal's** push notification integration with GoNative](https://gonative.io/docs/onesignal) to handle native push notifications to the user. In addition, I am sending out push notification messages from the server-side (C#/.NET in my case, but the server-side platform is irrelevant here).

I have already set up the necessary files to get universal links to open up in the native app rather than the browser (e.g. the `apple-app-association-file`). I am getting push notifications created and sent correctly.

However, I cannot get the push notification to link to a specific page on the application via the server-side API.

In OneSignal's [Create Notification API doc](https://(https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification)), it seems like you would send across either the `url`, `web_url`, or `app_url` parameter in your JSON request. However, none of these work correctly if you are using GoNative's push notification integration with OneSignal.

For instance, if you use the `url` or `app_url` parameter, you get a secondary browser pop-up *inside* your native app, instead of a load from just your native app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your own url value in the "Additional Data" property of your push notification. GoNative has [documentation](https://gonative.io/docs/open-url-from-notification) on this if you are creating push notifications from within OneSignal's web platform, but not specific guidance if you are programmatically creating push notifications via their API.

To do this via JSON, you add a `targetUrl` value to the `data` property.

```
{
   "app_id":"3baaa656-8832-4733-a88b-b83aba2598a7",
   "include_player_ids":[
      "3baaa656-8832-4733-a88b-b83aba2598a7",
      "3baaa656-8832-4733-a88b-b83aba2598a7"
   ],
   "headings":{
      "en":"DoneDone Project"
   },
   "subtitle":{
      "en":"#123: This is a bug!"
   },
   "contents":{
      "en":"Ka Wai Cheung created the task."
   },
   "data":{
      "targetUrl":"[LINK TO THE WEB APP]"
   }
}
```

Once you specify the `targetUrl`, it works. I hope this saves someone time one day!